# How to update another row's column after update on a column

Tags: php, mysql

As the title says I want to automatically update another row's column after an update on a specific column.

I have this table

```
id username direct_referral indirect_referral total_referral  referrer_id  paid
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    aj         100               56              156          1           1
2    john       100               40              140          1           1
3    michael    100               0               100          2           1
```

Now in this table `refferer_id` = id of referrer. For example aj has referred 'john' so he get 40% of the `total_referral` of john i.e.(140*40/100 = 56). john has referred michael so his `indirect_referral` will be 40% of michael i.e. (100*40/100 = 40).

Now I want to automatically increase `indirect_referral` of referrer by 40% of the `total_referral` of referral whenever a new user joins through his referral id and paid = 1.

Please tell me how can I do this process automatically and thanks in advance.

Comment: See about triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is tricky. But it might be solvable by a recursive SQL statement, also called CTE (common table expression).
There you have one initial query as an anchor member (the row you want to insert) and a recursive query that calls itself again and again.

Look at that link for an deeper explanation: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/

Another way of solving your problem is to make a lot of SQL queries, that you manage by your PHP code.